# Функция перестановок значений

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список чисел

```
['13', '24', '66', '78', '99']
```

Есть ли функция которая переставляет эти значения в определенном порядке?
Например:

```
['24', '66', '13', '99, '78']
```

Comment: Не понял, какая логика перестановки? Переставить в случайном порядке? Или как нужно задавать указания по перестановке?

Comment: Допустим есть список

Comment: [1,2,3,4,5]. 1 встает на место 4,
2 встает на место 1,
3 встает на место 3,
4 встает на место 5,
5 встает на место 2,
Вот так например

Comment: Переставлять в определенном порядке

Comment: Абсолютно непонятно зачем это может быть нужно. Если есть логика перестановки, то её можно описать. Если никакой логики нет, то можно просто создать новый список, т.к. создавать функцию и руками указывать все перестановки бессмысленно. Может я что-то не понимаю. Как вы себе представляете эту функцию? Что должно подаваться на вход для перестановки?

Comment: Я хотел сделать так, мы с помощью функции переставляем элементы списка(например наш исходный список [1,2,3,4,5]), затем мы получаем список [2,5,3,1,4], затем мы можем получившейся список [2,5,3,1,4] опять переставить с помощью нашей функции и получить исходный список [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Я это понял. Не понятна логика формирования нового списка и какая задача решается с помощью этой операции.

Comment: Ну просто случайно, я просто как для примера привел

Comment: @ДмитрийЮзов То, что Вам нужно, в математике называется [Перестановка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Для вашей задачи рекомендую посмотреть [Transposition Cipher](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography_with_python/cryptography_with_python_transposition_cipher.htm) и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098250/in-place-way-to-apply-a-permutation-to-a-list-inverse-of-sorting-by-key.

Comment: @ДмитрийЮзов И неплохо было бы привести в вопросе саму перестановку, которую Вы применили к изначальному списку, дабы у людей не возникало вопросов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна математическая [перестановка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). И то, что Вы хотите сделать, называется [перестановочным шифром](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80), ключом в котором является перестановка. Для шифрования используется перестановка, для расшифрования используется *обратная* к той, что использовалась при шифровании.

```py
import random

def gen_key(length: int) -> tuple:
    key = tuple(range(length))
    return tuple(sorted(key, key=lambda _: random.random()))


def get_inverse_permutation(perm: tuple) -> tuple:
    ret_perm = [0] * len(perm)
    for i, p in enumerate(perm):
        ret_perm[p] = i
    return tuple(ret_perm)


def encrypt(plain: list, perm: tuple) -> list:
    cipher = [plain[i] for i in perm]
    return cipher


def decrypt(cipher: list, perm: tuple) -> list:
    inv_perm = get_inverse_permutation(perm)
    return encrypt(cipher, inv_perm)


foo = ['13', '24', '66', '78', '99']

key = gen_key(len(foo))
print(f"Key: {key}")

cipher = encrypt(foo, key)
print(f"Cipher: {cipher}")

plain = decrypt(cipher, key)
print(plain == foo)
```

Comment: Да, это то что мне нужно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Случайным образом перемешать можно так:

```
from random import shuffle

a = ['13', '24', '66', '78', '99']
print("До перестановки:", a)
shuffle(a)
print("После перестановки:", a)
```

Comment: А можно как то определенно задать?

Comment: По какой логике? Опишите алгоритм перестановки словами.

Comment: ТСу нужно не случайным образом. Тут нужна обычная функция [перестановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: Есть массив, я его переставляю случайно, затем переставленный массив переставляю еще раз по тому же правилу, что и переставлял первый массив и получаю исходный

Comment: Дмитрий, определитесь - либо случайно, либо по правилу. Когда определитесь - внесите дополнения в свой _вопрос_, не надо писать кучу комментариев.

Answer (score 1):

> [1,2,3,4,5]. 1 встает на место 4, 2 встает на место 1, 3 встает на место 3, 4 встает на место 5, 5 встает на место 2, Вот так например

```
a = ['13', '24', '66', '78', '99']

b = [2, 5, 3, 1, 4] # задаем порядок сортировки
print([a[_ - 1] for _ in b) # ['24', '99', '66', '13', '78']
```

Или так:

```
print([x[0] for x in sorted(zip(a, b), key=lambda f: f[1], reverse=True)])
```